# What should I install in order to be able to use GTK in Python on Ubuntu?

Tags: python

In my source code I have:

```
import gtk
```

But when I run the script with python3 script.py command I get the following error. What package should I install to get it working?

Edit: my bad. here is the error:

```
ImportError: No module named gtk
```

Edit2: 
    Thanks for the answer, kaizer.se. But I'm still getting an error message. Take a look at the following code: 
    import pygtk, gtk
    pygtk.require('2.0')

```
def main():
    win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    s = u"привет 한국"
    win.set_title(s)
    win.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
    win.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    gtk.main()
```

When I run this script I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in file basics.py on line 6, but no encoding declared; see python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

Any idea how I may solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to actually include the error you're referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no big difference between how Python 3 and Python 2.6 handle unicode and international text, technically. The biggest difference is what the classes are called and what the defaults are.

So if you in Python 3 write:

```
s = "Grüß Gott"
```

you take this in Python 2.x:

```
# coding: UTF-8
s = u"Grüß Gott"
```

PyGTK always works with the UTF-8 encoding internally, and you can pass it unicode strings or UTF-8-encoded strings however you want.

The best model is to always work with unicode strings internally, and always convert strings as soon as they enter your program (say, you read a file). Again, in Python 3 this is more explicitly enforced, but the process is really exactly the same.

Addessing the updated question: I have already answered, Look closely at my Py 3 and Py 2.x examples! Hint: You must specify an encoding on the first line of every file, like this: `# coding: UTF-8`

You must also ask yourself, Baha, when you see an error message like this:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character
>   '\xd0' in file basics.py on line 6,
>   but no encoding declared; see
>   python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for
>   details

Did you read the message and see it says "no encoding declared"? Did you follow the link and read the information there? It would have been easy to solve this yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've edited the question and added some details. Could you take a look, plz? Thanks

Comment: thanks again, kaizer. honestly, i didn't pay attention to the error message. will be more attentive next time. thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

PyGtk doesn't support Python 3 yet. You might want to use Python 2.x and then you will need to install the `python-gtk2` package.

Comment: thank you, I was using pygtk with python2.x without any problems, but the only reason I wanted to use python3 was that I use unicode characters and I didn't want to do an extra step of encoding characters.